# difference between paypal create and pay_primary action type (adaptive payments)

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I know that paypal pay_primary is for chained payment and secondary receiver payment will be delayed and will only be paid on calling execute payment. Is there any way to use CREATE for creating a payment without paying even after redirecting the sender(i.e the sender clicks pay) other than using pre approval options, so that After creating a payment the execute payment can be called for making a payment from the application side?

This is asked because we are having one chained payment usecase in that pay key generated by calling PAY will be redirected to the sender and gets sender's approval **without payment** and then finally payment should be completed from application side using execute payment.

Thanks in advance

sri